# Why nameserver 8.8.8.8 can solve Ubuntu network connection issue

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, dns, nameserver

I have a Ubuntu 18.04 machine that cannot ping [www.google.com](http://www.google.com), it says `ping: unknown host www.google.com` However, after following some online help by

1. add
   `dns-nameserver 8.8.8.8` to the end of  `/etc/network/interfaces` which at first only had

> auto lo 
> iface lo inet loopback

2. add `nameserver 8.8.8.8` to the end of `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` which was originally empty.
3. add  `nameserver 8.8.8.8` to the end of `/etc/resolv.conf` which was also originally empty.
4. `sudo service networking restart`

I am happy to find that I can ping google.com now, but may I ask why steps 1. 2. 3. can solve this problem?

The network suddenly failed to work, but I don't think I have modified any of the three files. In other words, there was no `nameserver` or `dns-nameserver` line in those files at the beginning. By adding them, I am able to get the network back but will it have any negative effects such as network speed slowdown?

Some info may help
[image]

[image]

Comment: The DNS nameserver should have been dynamically set via the DHCP request. What is the DHCP server in your network? If it's the router, what is its model and what is its DHCP setting (screenshot would be best)?

Comment: @harrymc Hi Thank you! I dont find how to get the info you asked. Could you please tell me the command line? I have attached a picture. Would it be helpful? I am Linux newbie ;)

Comment: Use a browser to go to the router's configuration page and find the DHCP page.

Comment: I tried to use `10.177.48.1` which they say is the internal router address and also public IP address get [form](https://whatismyip.live/) but I cannot reach the addresses on the browser. Am I doing correctly with viewing my [router configuration](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1072361/how-can-i-find-the-ip-address-of-my-router)

Comment: The internal router address in your LAN is not your public IP on the internet. These are two distinct networks with the router as bridge. A router's IP is typically `192.168.1.1` or `192.168.0.1` or `10.0.0.1`. The two most-upvoted answers in [your link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1072361/how-can-i-find-the-ip-address-of-my-router) seem good.

Comment: Thanks but I cannot access any of them from my browser ( The two most-upvoted answers in the link both give me `10.177.48.1`

Comment: What is the output of `route -n` without your addition to `/etc/network/interfaces`?

Comment: @harrymc Please find `route -n` from the picture. It should be `10.177.48.1 `

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/108618).

Comment: It seems you're on Docker, which explains the funny IP address. Your post is still missing important information.